# Websocket Push Notifications not working AFTER spring boot upgrade from 1.2.0 to 2.1.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

This is about a spring **boot** + angularjs web application which uses **websocket + stompjs** to send push notifications.

I upgraded from Spring boot **1.2.0 to 2.1.3** recently. **Before** this upgrade websocket (push notifications) was **working fine for couple of years**.

I just upgraded spring boot and websocket related **code remains exactly same**, but it is **not** working now.

**Not working means:**

1. Below line executed at server side **without** any error/exception.

`simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/notify", payload);`

2. Chrome **debugger** receives only "h" (heartbeat) but not the actual message.

I have **no clue** because,

- server side code executed successfully **till the last line**.
- websocket session established, I can get heartbeat messages, but no error at client side as well.

**Code (but this same code works well with Spring boot 1.2.0:**

**1. Config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Value("${server.sessionTimeout}")
    long sessionTimeoutInSecs;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/notify").withSockJS();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
        ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
        // in milliseconds
        container.setMaxSessionIdleTimeout(sessionTimeoutInSecs * 1000);
        return container;
    }
}
```

**2. Message sending code:**

```
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/notify", payload);
```

**3. Client code:**

```
(function() {
  myApp.factory('autoUpdateTasksService', function($resource, $q, $log) {
    var initSockets, notify, reconnect, socket, _callback;
    _callback = null;
    socket = {
      client: null,
      stomp: null
    };
    initSockets = function() {
      socket.client = new SockJS('/notify');
      socket.stomp = Stomp.over(socket.client);
      socket.stomp.connect({}, function() {});
      socket.client.onopen = function() {
        var subscription1;
        subscription1 = socket.stomp.subscribe("/topic/notify", notify);
        //$log.log('socket connected');
      };
    };
    reconnect = function() {
      setTimeout(initSockets, 1000);
    };
    notify = function(message) {
         try{
              var taskNotifyObject;
                  if (message.body) {
                    taskNotifyObject = angular.fromJson(message.body);
                    //$log.log(taskNotifyObject);
                    var notificationArray=[];
                    notificationArray.push(taskNotifyObject);
                    _callback(notificationArray);
                  } else {
                    //$log.log("empty message");
                  }
             } catch(e){
                // alert(e.message); 
                 }
                };
            return {
              init: function(callback) {
                _callback = callback;
                initSockets();
              }
            };
  });

}).call(this);
```

Is anything changed in spring framework between versions?

How I can debug/find **where the message is lost?**

Answer (score 1):

**Rootcause:** AFTER the upgrade, the code in my question was **failed to create connection** between server and client ( failed to created **websocketSession**).

**Changing code** as below solves the problem, but I am **NOT** sure why this solution is working,

*if anyone explains **why** this solution is working, It would be a great help.*

**1. Config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Value("${server.servlet.session.timeout}")
    long sessionTimeoutInSecs;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/notify").addInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
        ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
        // in milliseconds
        container.setMaxSessionIdleTimeout(sessionTimeoutInSecs * 1000);
        return container;
    }

    /**
     * DefaultSimpUserRegistry is the replacement of MySessionRegistry ( Custom UserSessionRegistry ) after upgrade to Spring 5.
     * Below required with Spring 4.
     * import org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.UserSessionRegistry;
        @Repository
        public class MySessionRegistry implements UserSessionRegistry, ApplicationListener<AbstractSubProtocolEvent> {
     * 
     */ 
    @Bean
    public DefaultSimpUserRegistry defaultSimpUserRegistry() {
        DefaultSimpUserRegistry userRegistry = new DefaultSimpUserRegistry();
        return userRegistry;
    }
}
```

**2. Message sending code:**

```
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.DefaultSimpUserRegistry;

@Autowired
DefaultSimpUserRegistry defaultSimpUserRegistry;

.....

SimpUser simpUser = defaultSimpUserRegistry.getUser(payload.getUserName());

if(simpUser != null && simpUser.hasSessions()) {
     template.convertAndSendToUser(payload.getUserName(), "/queue/notify", payload);
}
```

**3. Client code:**

```
(function() {
  myApp.factory('autoUpdateTasksService', function($resource, $q, $log) {
    var initSockets, notify, reconnect, socket, _callback;
    _callback = null;
    socket = {
      client: null,
      stomp: null
    };
    getContextPath = function() {
        return window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2));
    };
    initSockets = function() {
        //socket.addr = "wss://" + window.location.host + "/notify";
        socket.addr = ((window.location.protocol && (window.location.protocol.indexOf("https") >= 0)) ? "wss://" : "ws://") + window.location.host + getContextPath() + "/notify";
        socket.client = Stomp.client(socket.addr); //new SockJS('/notify');
        socket.client.connect({}, function () {
          $log.log("Connected to websocket through " + socket.addr);
          socket.client.subscribe("/user/queue/notify", notify);
        }, function (err) {
          $log.log("Error when connection to websocket " + socket.addr + ".\n" + err);
        });
    };
```

> How I can debug/find where the message is lost?

**To validate client-server connectivity** ( or creation of websocketSession), I added below **listener**.

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SessionConnectedEvent;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SessionSubscribeEvent;

@Component
public class WebSocketListener implements ApplicationListener <ApplicationEvent> {

            //WebSocket session created
            if (appEvent instanceof SessionConnectedEvent){
                StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(((SessionConnectedEvent) appEvent).getMessage());
                logger.info("SessionConnectedEvent: STOMP WebSocket session created for the user: {}", sha.getUser().getName());
            }

            //subscribed to websocketSession
            if (appEvent instanceof SessionSubscribeEvent){
                StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(((SessionSubscribeEvent) appEvent).getMessage());                
                logger.info("SessionSubscribeEvent: User {} subscribed to WebSocket session, destination: {}", sha.getUser().getName(), sha.getDestination());
            }
//            
//            if (appEvent instanceof BrokerAvailabilityEvent){
//                logger.info("BrokerAvailabilityEvent: {}", appEvent.toString());
//            }
        }
}
```